# Notify OSD не работает

Tags: ubuntu

Notify OSD не отображает уведомления, никакие. Поисковики ничего путного не выдают. Команда **notify-send "Система оповещения" "Пример работы" -i gtk-info** ничего не выводит.
Ubuntu 13.10, комп: AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 4000+ × 2, GeForce 9800 GT, NVIDIA Driver Version: 319.32. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: У меня на дебьяне работает , дома вечером посмотрю на юбунте.

Comment: А вам зачем , просто я для нотифи на экран более модную фичу юзаю , могу поделиться )

Comment: Поделитесь, если не сложно.Неудобно без уведомлений. Одно то, что сообщения Empathy не всплывают в уведомлении уже дискомфортно, подключение/отключение флешек, дисков и т.п. и другие системные уведомления. Да и, раз есть, должно работать.

Answer (score 1):

Может просто не установлен пакет libnotify-bin?

> sudo apt-get install libnotify-bin

для проверки киньте в эмулятор терминала что-нибудь типа этого:

> notify-send 'Ух ты, говорящая рыба!'

Comment: "Уже установлена самая новая версия libnotify-bin". Ничего не понимаю. Вроде все есть. Чего он хочет?! Что не так?